# How to assign text into textarea (any multiline text) in asp.net mvc view from controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to set data into a textarea in asp.net mvc razor page (.cshtml) from controller in C#. My code snippet as following:
I am not able to assign data into model.

In cshtml:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(b => b.query, new { Value = ViewBag.query, height = "500px;" })
```

In controller:

```
ViewBag.query = "Hello";
model.query = ViewBag.query;
```

In Model:

```
[Display(Name = "Query")]
public string query { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason why you should use the Value parameter when the value for the field has been assigned in the controller. I am not sure why this is not working because you didn't provide the whole code so i'll just try to fill in the blanks.

Model:

```
public class ModelName
{
   [Display(Name = "Query")]
   public string query { get; set; }
}
```

In the controller, make sure you return the model.

```
public class ControllerName : Controller
{

   public ActionResult ActionName()
   {

      ViewBag.query = "Hello";
      var model = new ModelName
      {
        query = ViewBag.query
      }
      return View(model)
   }   
}
```

In the view, make sure the object type is referenced on the page...

```
@model ApplicationName.Models.ModelName
```

So if anywhere in the view, you can get the value for the text area this way.

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.query, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Add Placeholder", id = "textarea", autocomplete = "off", @rows = "10", style = "width: 70%; max-width: 100%;" }
```

You can always change the style or don't use any at all depending on what you want.

Comment: in html model => model.query is not working. For first time return only ',' then if i click once more then return ', Hello,' then ', Hello, Hello,' and so on.
In textboxfor it is working fine.
Actually I need a multiline textbox control in cshtml page where have to show the text "Hello" from controller

Comment: @subhayan Can you please edit the question with a screenshot of what the problem is. Also can you please add more context to the code so i can see if something is missing. Not sure why it would work for textbox and not textarea

Answer (score 0):

You can define multiline textbox in following way :

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Body, 10, 15, null)
```